# glm::rotation doesn't work properly OpenGL C++

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm learning OpenGL and now I'm learning more from matrix and I wanted to rotate my texture, but when I'm doing that, it's rotating wrong (idk, only one triangle? I don't know how to explain that). You can see my code and picture with problem below. Thanks for any help. My loop code:

```
/* My Vertex Array with Struct */
struct Vertex
{
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec2 texCoord;

    Vertex(glm::vec3 pos, glm::vec2 tcoord)
        : position(pos), texCoord(tcoord) {}
};

Vertex vertices[] = {
    Vertex(glm::vec3(100.f, 100.f, 0.f), glm::vec2(0.f, 1.f)),
    Vertex(glm::vec3(100.f, 400.f, 0.f), glm::vec2(0.f, 0.f)),
    Vertex(glm::vec3(400.f, 100.f, 0.f), glm::vec2(1.f, 1.f)),
    Vertex(glm::vec3(400.f, 400.f, 0.f), glm::vec2(1.f, 0.f))
};


while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glm::mat4 proj = glm::ortho(0.f, 800.f, 600.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glm::mat4 trans(1.0f);
    trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(0.5, -0.5, 0));
    trans = glm::rotate(trans, glm::radians(1.f), glm::vec3(1.f));
    proj *= trans;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

My Loading Texture Code:

```
GLuint loadTexture(std::string texturePath, int slot)
{
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);

    int x, y, bpp;
    unsigned char* file = stbi_load(texturePath.c_str(), &x, &y, &bpp, 4);

    GLuint texture = 0;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    bindTexture(texture, slot);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, x, y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, file);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    bindTexture(0, 0);

    if (file)
        stbi_image_free(file);

    return texture;
}
```

[Image with Problem (Don't look at picture, I just took a random picture from Memes folder lol)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nb8s.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mesh is clipped by the near and far plane of the orthographic projection. Increase the distance to the near and far plane:

<s>`glm::mat4 proj = glm::ortho(0.f, 800.f, 600.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);`</s>

```cpp
glm::mat4 proj = glm::ortho(0.f, 800.f, 600.f, 0.f, -1000.f, 1000.f);
```

The projection matrix defines the area (volume) with respect to the observer (viewer) which is projected onto the viewport. At orthographic projection, this area (volume) is defined by 6 distances (left, right, bottom, top, near and far) to the viewer's position. All the objects which are in the volume are "visible" on the viewport. All the objects which are out (or partly out) of this volume are clipped at the borders of the volume.

Comment: Yeah, It worked now. Thanks for help and explanation!

Comment: Yeah I know, but I have a message I can do it in 2 minutes (for now).Thanks